# Jersey as REST client, maintaining a connection (or validating connection)

Tags: rest, connection, jersey

I am getting started with Jersey 2.1 which I want to use as a client, to make REST calls to someone elses web service.

I have been working through the tutorials, and I think I understand how to open a connection, and make calls to the web service.

The question I have is, since my service will persist, and have to process events when they happen, how do I manage and maintain session connectivity?

I have been trying to understand if I need to:

1. Close connections? This does not seem to be discussed.  So are the implicitly auto-closed after making a call?
2. If not auto-closed, can I check the state to see if a Connection is still valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying connections are opened for each request and closed after the response is received and entity is processed (entity is read).

```
final WebTarget target = ... some web target
Response response = target.path("resource").request().get();
System.out.println("Connection is still open.");
System.out.println("string response: " + response.readEntity(String.class));
System.out.println("Now the connection is closed.");
```

If you don't read the entity, then you need to close the response manually by response.close(). Also if the entity is read into an input stream (by response.readEntity(InputStream.class)), the connection stays open until you finish reading from the InputStream. In that case, the InputStream or the Response should be closed manually at the end of reading from InputStream.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the "[How To Use Jersey Client Efficiently](https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/how_to_use_jersey_client)", closing response connection is one of the best practices to maintain the performance of your application from client side point of view. Also on another note, it also helps to close the client connection as well.

Key Points are :

- To close response after collecting/reading all the information needed in your client code.
- And to close client connection after completing all the CRUD operation with in your client service class. This is very important in situation where you get some-type of connection/service-endpoint related exception during the service call.
- It's also worth mentioning about connection and read time out.

Example:

client.setConnectTimeout(10000);// In millisecond.

client.setReadTimeout(60000); // In millisecond.

Hope this helps.